# What does web3's approve do before a token sell?

Tags: ether, web3.py, erc-20-approve

I'm trying to implement a bot with python and web3 from some code  examples.

All of them call the `approve` function before selling a token? What is this function for and is it necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The approve function is called by an account to approve that other accounts can handle its tokens. It is generally used to allow swap houses to swap their tokens, but it is really dangerous, because a lot of people don't read what they are accepting through MetaMask. Unfortunately this function is also used by scans to steal tokens, because once you approve someone to transfer your tokens, they can simply transfer your tokens at will.

The approve function is usually used together with the transferFrom function. Once account A is authorized (via approve function) by account B to transfer its tokens, then account A will use the transferFrom function to transfer the tokens from account B (parameter _from) to whomever it wants (parameter _to).

Answer (score 0):

ERC-20 `approve()` function is a legacy implementation failure from all the way back from 2014.

Unfortunately, the ERC-20 token standard got very popular and all tokens copied `approve()` and `tranferFrom()` logic that is not very sensible. Strictly, it should not be necessary, but that's how all ERC-20 tokens have been coded. This has been fixed in newer token standards, but unfortunately these standards have not gained popularity.

[More about the topic on here](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1299647432817606656).

Comment: Thanks Buddy! So is  this  function needed  before  every  sell  or just before the first one?

Comment: You need to adjust `approve()`  before every swap, or you can create infinite `approve()` that is insecure

Answer (score 0):

When a call is made to a contract, the contract knows who made the call (i.e. the sender). When you call token.transfer(to,amount) you are the sender, and you are asking the token contract to  transfer "amount" of tokens to the "to" address. Since it's "you" (the sender) requesting the transfer of your own balance, that's all that's needed.

In other cases, you (the sender) want to tell the token contract that it's ok for a different contract (e.g., Uniswap) to move your token balance on your behalf. For example, when you want to swap USDT for something, you need to allow Uniswap to take your USDT.

Therefore, you first call usdt.approve(spender,amount).  Later, the "spender" contract (Uniswap) will use that approval to transfer up to "amount" tokens from YOUR balance to itself (or somewhere else).